# Display a div using a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like  to display a div on a webpage when a user clicks on a button.

Does someone know how to do this ?

My code, so far, is :

```
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso 8859-1" />
        </head>
        <body>
          <input id="text" type="text" size="60" value="Type your text here" />
          <input type="button" value="When typing whatever text display the div balise on the page" onclick="check();" />

          <script type="text/javascript">

        function check() {
              //Display my div balise named level0;
        }

          </script>

        </body>
      </html>
```

Thanks,

Bruno

EDIT: All my code (I've erased it because it was too long and not very clear)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `document.createElement("div")` to actually make the div. Then you can populate the div using `innerHTML` for the text. After that, add it to the body using `appendChild`. All told, it can look like this:

```
function check() {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = document.getElementById("text").value;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

This will add a div every time the button is pressed. If you want to update the div each time instead, you can declare the `div` variable outside the function:

```
var div;
function check() {
    if (!div) {
        div = document.createElement("div");
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }

    div.innerHTML = document.getElementById("text").value;
}
```

If you have the div already in the page with an id of "level0", try:

```
function check() {
    var div = document.getElementById("level0");
    div.innerHTML = document.getElementById("text").value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried  and it doesn't work : my div already exists (named level0) and when I put document.body.appendchild("level0") nothing happens.

Comment: @Tikhon No but without the click I can display it.

Comment: So the div _isn't_ in the page, you just have its id? Or is it in the page and invisible?

Comment: Because I did not write all of it for concision matters but without the click it works ok ( <body><div id="level0"></div></body>).

Comment: Well, I added a bit to the end of the answer, which might work if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your commitment :-) But unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: Even in your second code sample, I can't really find where the div with id "level0" gets created.

Comment: It gets created when the page is loaded (<body onload="init()">)

Answer (score 2):

A quick search on google gave me this example:

[Demo of hide/show div](http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/hide-layer2.php)

The source-code for that example is:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Demo of Show hide div layer onclick of buttons</title> 
<META NAME="DESCRIPTION" CONTENT="Displaying and hiding div layers through button clicks"> 
<META NAME="KEYWORDS" CONTENT="Show layer, hide layer, display div, hide div, button on click, button on click event, div property, div style set"> 
<style type="text/css"> 
div {
position: absolute;
left: 250px;
top: 200px;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
width: 280px;
padding: 10px;
color: black;
border: #0000cc 2px dashed;
display: none;
}
</style> 


<script language="JavaScript"> 
function setVisibility(id, visibility) {
document.getElementById(id).style.display = visibility;
}

</script> 
</head> 
<body> 

<input type=button name=type value='Show Layer' onclick="setVisibility('sub3', 'inline');";><input type=button name=type value='Hide Layer' onclick="setVisibility('sub3', 'none');";> 

<div id="sub3">Message Box</div> 
<br><br> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Paste this code somewhere in your `body`

```
      <div id="myDiv" style="display:none">
          Hello, I am a div
      </div>
```

Add this snippet into your `check()` function to display the otherwise-hidden content.

```
      document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
```

You could also change the `div` content programmatically thus:

```
      document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "Breakfast time";
```

... would change the text to 'Breakfast time'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried  and it doesn't work : my div already exists (named level0) and when I put document.getElementById("level0").style.display = "block" nothing happens.

Comment: Because I did not write all of it for concision matters but without the click it works ok ( <body><div id="level0"></div></body>).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into jquery, it'll make your life 100 times easier.
Jquery is a javascript library (script) that you include and it allows you to manipulate the DOM very easily.

Start by adding the latest Jquery to your head which will allow you to use something like $(document).ready(  )
The function inside .ready( fn ) is a callback function; it get called when the document is ready.

$("#lnkClick") is a selector (http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready( function() {
                $("#lnkClick").click( function() {
                    $("#level0").attr("style", "display: block;width: 100px; height: 100px; border: solid 1px blue;");
                });
             });
         </script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div id="level0" style="display:none;">
         </div>

         <a href="#" id="lnkClick">Click me</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Of course this code can be made cleaner. You want to check: http://api.jquery.com/click/
There are plenty of examples.

Best of luck with Jquery!

Comment: +1 for jquery, but i think your code example is overly complicated

Answer (score 1):

you really should be using [jquery](http://jquery.com/) , there's a little bit of a learning curve but once you get it, developing web apps is much easier.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#show_div_button").click(function() {
      $("#div_to_show").show();
      return false;
   });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#" id="show_div_button">Click Me to Show the Div</a>
  <div style="display:none" id="div_to_show">I will be shown when the link is clicked</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can copy and paste the above code into a file and launch it in your browser to test